# c++ method argument class reference

Tags: c++

I'm sorry to ask such a newbie question.
Here is my problem :

```
MyClass* c = new MyClass("test");
method(c);//error cannot convert MyClass* to MyClass
```

the definition :

```
method(MyClass c);
```

should I also define ?

```
method(MyClass* c);
```

I don't want to duplicate the code, what is the proper way ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you are worried about memory, trying `method(MyClass& c)` or `method(const MyClass& c)` depending on what you need.

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Did you mean `MyClass *c = new MyClass("test");` ?

Comment: Did you mean `MyClass c("test");`? `new`ing things is a recipe for a disaster.

Comment: Note also that you may choose to create the item with 'new', but you will need to call 'delete' on that pointer when you are done with it to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant MyClass *c = new MyClass("test"); I just edited.

Comment: Why on earth is everyone recommending `new` and pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're clearly a Java programmer! First of all, you will need to do:

```
MyClass* c = new MyClass("test");
```

Note that `c` is a "pointer to `MyClass`" - this is necessary because the `new` expression gives you a pointer to the dynamically allocated object.

Now, to pass this to a function that takes a `MyClass` argument, you will need to dereference the pointer. That is, you will do:

```
method(*c);
```

Note that because the function takes a `MyClass` by value (not a reference), the object will be copied into your function. The `MyClass` object inside `method` will be a copy of the object you allocated earlier. The type of the argument depends on exactly what you want your function to do and convey. If instead you want a reference to the object, so that modifying the object inside the function will modify the `c` object outside the function, you need your function to take a `MyClass&` argument - a reference to `MyClass`.

If you were to have the argument be of type `MyClass*`, then you could simply do:

```
method(c);
```

This will give you similar semantics to passing a reference, because the pointer `c` will be copied into the function but the object that pointer refers to will still be the dynamically allocated `MyClass` object. That is, if inside the function you modify `*d`, the object pointed to by `c` is also modified.

Passing a raw pointer like this is usually not a very good approach. The function will have to explicitly check that the pointer is not null, otherwise your program may crash under certain conditions. If you want pass-by-reference semantics, use reference types - it's what they're for.

However, you're better off not dynamically allocating your `MyClass` object in the first place. I guess you're only using `new` because you did it a lot in Java. In C++, the `new` expression is used to *dynamically allocate* an object. More often than not, you do not want to dynamically allocate an object. It is perfectly fine to create it with automatic storage duration, which you would do like so:

```
MyClass c("test");
method(c);
```

It is considered very good practise in C++ to avoid pointers and dynamic allocation unless you have a good reason. It will only lead you to more complicated code with more room for errors and bugs. In fact, the code you've given already has a problem because you didn't `delete c;`. When you do as I have just suggested, you don't need to explicitly delete anything, because the object will be destroyed when it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

```
MyClass *c = new MyClass("test");

method(*c);
```

it works if you defined a method like `method(MyClass c)`

But if you define you method like `method(MyClass *c);`

then it should be

```
MyClass *c = new MyClass("test");
method(c);
```

The two alternatives have consequences depending on what you want to do with the object you have created.

Comment: This will cause a *COPY* of c to be passed into method. Are you sure that's the right thing to do? This is just bad advice. If someone asks you "how do I put this square peg into a round hole" the answer isn't "with a hammer." The answer is "what are you trying to do?" And so here you should be asking the OP to explain what he's actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: I agree, but I just got down voted for that same response...  :(